# using script to automatically download python packages from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p

Tags: python

I am using some existing scripts to download and install various python packages

Like this

"https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/${SRCNAME}/${SRCNAME}-${PV}.tar.gz

But I want to know more about this link "https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/"

When I paste this on browser it does not open any page.

I cant seems to find any information on how this link is known to the developers who download packages

Comment: You might not be able to see anything there as it might not be allowed. But in any case, to download you need full part for tar.gz file. Are you trying to download whole PyPI. Else you will anyway have the names.

Comment: No I am trying to download pysnmp ..

Comment: But is there any website which mentions about this path?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi is the website listing the python packages.